# Keeping dice after giving in Dogs in the Vineyard

Tags: dogs-in-the-vineyard

In the revised edition there's a rule about keeping two dice if somebody gives in a conflict. Can anybody spell it out for me?

What are circumstances, which dice, when who gives, who gets to use them and when?

Thanks!

Comment: The version I have is copyright 2004 by D. Vincent Baker, GenCon '05 - that's not the revised edition, yes?

Comment: That's the edition I have, too. So no, but thanks for looking.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but -- to speculate -- could it have to do with multi-party conflicts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vincent explains this on [the Forge](http://www.indie-rpgs.com/archive/index.php?topic=16052.0) (where there is even more information).

> **The rule change**
>
> I'm the GM. My NPCs take a stack of fallout, but nobody cares if they live or die or what.
>
> How it used to work: I pass all their fallout dice, unrolled, to the players, to roll with their dice in the followup conflict.
>
> How it works now: I roll their fallout dice as I would if we cared about them. However, instead of assigning fallout, I pass the two highest showing dice across to the players for their side of the followup conflict. They don't reroll them.
>
> This is to make followup conflicts less humiliating for me as the GM.
>
> **The new rule**
>
> If you give instead when it's your turn to raise, you get to "cut your losses."
>
> Take your highest single showing die and set it aside. After you roll your dice for the followup conflict, add the "cut your losses" die back into the mix, without rerolling it.
>
> This is to break the thing where people are by default staying in every conflict past when they should be ditching out.

Comment: Aha. OK, that is the rule in the edition Jmstar and I have (in case anyone gets confused). Cool!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a cite:

"If you give instead of raising, it's called "cutting your losses," and you get to keep the single highest die showing on your side. Carry it into a followup conflict without rerolling it. It's on page 64 of the illustrated book, under "Giving," and then again on page 67, under "Followup Conflicts."